# How to avoid Mockito InvalidUseOfMatchersException

Tags: junit, mockito

I have such code fragment:

```
@Test
public void itShouldInvokeExecuteMethod() {
    when(dbHandlerService.getQuery(anyMap(), anyString())).thenReturn(anyString());
    dbHandlerController.createSchema(new HashMap<String, String>());
    verify(dbHandlerService).execute(anyString());
}
```

When I run tests, the InvalidUseOfMatchersException occurs in line

```
when(dbHandlerService.getQuery(anyMap(), anyString())).thenReturn(anyString());
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a concrete value. `anyString()` in `thenReturn` is wrong.

Try

```
when(dbHandlerService.getQuery(anyMap(), anyString())).thenReturn("");
```

Comment: OMG that was simple. Thanks :)